# Rename Pandas column inside Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas

I am new to Pandas/Python and am having trouble.  I have a dictionary object,  "dict" which looks something like:

```
In[107]:dict
Out[107]: 
{'Thing1':
 Date
 2014-09-15        0.12
 2014-09-15        0.17
 2014-09-16        0.57
 dtype: float64,

'Thing2':
 Date
 2014-11-10    30.00
 2014-12-26    25.00
 2014-12-29    30.00
 dtype: float64,

 'Thing3'
 Date
 2014-09-26      61.80
 2014-09-30     151.58
 2014-10-06     749.87
 dtype: float64}
```

"Thing1", "Thing2", and "Thing3" are Pandas DataFrames with a date time index "Date".

I would like to rename the unnamed "zero" column so that my data looks something like this:

```
In[107]:dict
Out[107]: 
{'Thing1':
 Date              New Title
 2014-09-15        0.12
 2014-09-15        0.17
 2014-09-16        0.57
 dtype: float64,

'Thing2':
 Date          New Title
 2014-11-10    30.00
 2014-12-26    25.00
 2014-12-29    30.00
 dtype: float64,

 'Thing3'
 Date           New Title
 2014-09-26      61.80
 2014-09-30     151.58
 2014-10-06     749.87
 dtype: float64}
```

I am using a for loop to create this dictionary.  As I loop through I add "Thing1" then "Thing2" and finally "Thing3".  I would like to either rename the column or give it a name at the time I create it.  I have focused on attempting to rename the column.  Below is a sample of what I have been trying...

I'm pretty sure my issue is that I can't figure out how to index into the dictionary.  I have tried various permutations of the following:

```
dict["Thing{0}".format(x)].rename(index=Earn_Cumulative["Thing{0}".format(x)], columns={0:"New Title"})
```

I have tried with and without an index.  I have tried using "", "0", "value" and several others for the current column name.

I have tried using every combination I can think of.  I'm at my whits end.  A helping hand to walk me through this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Are you sure that the data inside the `dict` is a DataFrame? From the looks of it, it appears to be a Series, which acts more like a single column with an index, but has different conventions for adding a name than what DataFrame columns have.

Comment: I suppose it looks a lot like a TimeSeries... I will reevaluate my approach.

Comment: Yep, it was a series.  I used J Bradley's solution based on this question.  Much appreciated input from all parties.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to rename a columns for dataframes stored in a `dict`:

```
#create a frame with a timeseries index and a unnamed column
rng = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2014','1/2/2014','1/2/2014', '1/3/2014', '1/3/2014','1/4/2014','1/6/2014']))
df = pd.DataFrame({None:[5,6,7,8,2,3,6],'date':rng})
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# add frames to dict
frames ={}
for i in range(3):
    frames[i] = df
```

use paramater `inplace=True` to make sure the frame is acted on inplace:

```
#loop through dicts using keys and rename column names in place
for k in frames.keys():
    frames[k].rename(columns=({None:'Something'}), inplace=True)
```

If they are in fact `series` in a `dict`:

```
series_dict ={}
for i in range(3):
    series_dict[i] = df[None]
```

To name a series you just need to assign to `name`:

```
for k in frames.keys():
    series_dict[k].name = 'New_Name'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I believe my data is actually a time series.  The "Date" column in my example above is actually the index.

Comment: It is a series with a datetime index,  like in my second example. You can use `for k in frames.keys(): series_dict[k].name = 'New_Name'`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store a dictionary of `DataFrames`, you might want to consider working with a `Pandas.Panel` object.  This should work:

```
for df in dict.values:
    df['Date'] = 'new data'
```

DataFrames are stored in dictionary by references, so overwriting their data while they're in a dictionary should would without the need to create a new dictionary or anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I went with J Bradely's solution, but I may circle back to yours as it looks like it is simple and headed in the right direction.